# Preventing form submission when Enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with a disabled submit button. Even though the user can't press this button, he can still hit Enter to submit the form. How do I prevent that?

Comment: Possible Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=prevent+submit+form+enter , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923683/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter-2 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906376/safari-disable-form-submit-on-enter

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming HTML:

```
<form id="myForm"> ...
```

You can do this with JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function () {
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 31):

If you want to *completely* disable the form submit (However I am wondering why the whole `<form>` element is then there in first place), then you need to let its `submit` event handler return `false`.

So, basically:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

You can add it using Javascript/DOM manipulation during onload as previous answerers pointed out.

If you *only* want to disable the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to submit the form, then you need to let its `keydown` event handler return `false` when the `key` of the event matches `Enter` (this one is crossbrowser compatible and covers both the default Enter as well as the numpad Enter!).

```
<form onkeypress="return event.key != 'Enter';">
```

This however also disables the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in any `<textarea>` elements in the form. If you have any of them and you would like to keep them functioning, then you'll need to remove the `onkeydown` from the `<form>` and copy it over all `<input>` and `<select>` elements. [jQuery](https://jquery.com) can be helpful in this:

```
$('input, select').keydown(event => event.key != 'Enter');
```

#### See also:

- [Prevent users from submitting a form by hitting Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-a-form-by-hitting-enter)

Comment: The last line won't work till you add "event" as a parametr to keypress callback .keypress(function(event){});

Comment: @tylik: You're right, I overlooked that part. Answer has been fixed. Thank you for notifying.

Comment: The last keypress function is a beauty.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of implementing two methods of disabling form submitting, add an event handler to form's onsubmit which will check the `disabled` property of the button:

```
myForm.onsubmit = function () { 
    if (myForm.mySubmit.disabled) 
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Say you had a form with an id of "myForm":

```
<form id="myForm" action="some_file" method="post">
   ...
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById( "myForm").onsubmit = function() {
          return false;
    };
    //or with jQuery: $( '#myForm' ).submit( function() { return false; } );
</script>
```

Comment: If you're putting `<script>` after `<form>` then you don't need to wait for `onload`. You could potentially be losing the anti-submit if images are still loading, for example.

Comment: Eh, how many times did you edit this answer? I lost the count. First it was an oneliner, then a copypaste of @Matt, then a window.onload, then code formatting, then jQuery. Did I miss some more? :)

Comment: @BalusC, um I never copy-pasted. Just happens to be that `myForm` was the same `id` that we used. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to edit the onsubmit event of the form, you can do it like this.
Add this to the text input:

```
onKeyPress="return noEnter(event)"
```

And this to the header:

```
    function noEnter(e)
    {
        var key;
        // firefox vs. ie
        (window.event) ? key = window.event.keyCode : key = e.which;
        (key == 13) ? return false : return true;
    }
```

easier to pull of with jquery.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery Solution:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form[name="form"]').keypress( function(evt){
    return !(evt.which==13 && evt.target.type!='textarea');
  });
  $('form[name="form"] input[type="submit"]').attr('tabIndex',-1); // this prevents submit also by spacebar (keyCode==32)
  //$('form[name="form"]').submit(function(){ alert('test'); return false; }); // test
});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting to SO. Next  time, adding some explanatory text would be helpful. Just a few lines explaining what the code is doing. Like why setting tabIndex to -1 prevents the spacebar from submitting

Comment: Thanks Devon, I'll give it more description next time.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function () {
    return false;
};
```

These codes doesn't work on Chrome and Safari. It submits form to action url.

But `<form onsubmit="return false;">` is useful.