# On enter key input number function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a little form with three checkbox and one of them is attached to an 'input number' and if the checkbox is checked is takes the number and calls a function.

The problem is that if I enter the number and press the ENTER key the page reloads. I suppose that its because I'm submitting the form to nowhere.

How can I change that to on enter not send the form but call the function again?

Thanks.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="checkbox" id="filterLenght" value="lenght" onClick="redraw()">
        MinLenght
        <br>
    </span>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="filterLenghtNumber" value="200">
</div>
```

Comment: you should provide the code.

Comment: where is the javascript?

Comment: What JS?? there's only a onClick function on the checkbox, what I want is if there is a way to do like an 'onEnter: redraw()' and deactivate the theoricall 'onEnter: submit' in the input number.

Comment: what does redraw() do?

Comment: where is the form in your html?

Comment: It was a generic question. Really do you need all that info? @user733421

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing form submission when Enter is pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802887/preventing-form-submission-when-enter-is-pressed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to deactivate the 'enter -> submit':

```
        $("#formID").submit(function() {
            return false;
        });
```

The way to call a function when press key ENTER in a input type:

```
        $("#InputID").keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                redraw();
            }
        });
```